# Rails Merge child errors with Parent errors

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, associations, rails-activerecord

I've got the following two (sanitized/stylized) models:

```
 class DrivingExam < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :dmv_rules
   has_many :invigilator_assignments, as: :assignable
   has_many :invigilator, through: :invigilator_assignments

   validate do |record|
     record.invigilator_assignments.each do |i|
       next if i.valid?
       i.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
         errors.add_to_base(msg)
       end
     end
   end
 end



 class InvigilatorAssignment  < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :invigilator_id

   belongs_to :assignable, polymorphic: true
   belongs_to :invigilator

   validates :invigilator_id, presence: true

   validates_each :invigilator do |record, attr, value|
     if record.assignable.is_a?(DrivingExam) && !value.no_scheduling_conflicts?
       record.errors.add attr, "This Invigilator has a scheduling conflict"
     end

   end
 end
```

These get called from the `DrivingExamController` by way of:

```
 if @driving_exam.save
```

The expected behaviour is that the model should return false on the validation and join the child messages into the parent errors hash and pass this up to the controller.

What happens instead is that the page fails to save (this is good) with a 422(this is weird) and does not pass the messages.

By adding `puts` statements throughout the above code, I have established that:

1) The if condition within `validates_each` is successful, and the `record.errors` array is thus set inside the `InvigilatorAssignment` model.

2) In the `validate do` loop the invigilator assignment is valid and has no errors

3) the `validate do` loop runs before the `validates_each` loop

So the question is: How do I ensure that the `DrivingExam` validates `InvigilatorAssignment` and merges its error messages onto its own error hash.

Comment: ```errors.add_to_base``` has been dropped from Rails 3.0 and above and should be replaced with:

```errors[:base] << "Student Error: #{msg}"```

Answer (score 3):

Refer to this question on stackoverflow :

[Ruby on Rails: how to get error messages from a child resource displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680016/ruby-on-rails-how-to-get-error-messages-from-a-child-resource-displayed)

It is similar to what you want.

Comment: I have referred to the above stackoverflow post, in fact it is incorporated on my DrivingController in the validate loop.

However, that does not appear to fix my issue.