# How to populate parent object in nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have two model with following association

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories, reject_if: proc { |attributes| (attributes['user_id'].blank? || attributes['numbers'].blank?) }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

and

```
    class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :article

      validate :mytest

      def mytest
        valid = self.article.phase_id != Category::STD["author"] && self.article.user_id == self.user_id
if !valid
self.article.errors.add(:base, 'Not admin user error')
end
      end
    end
```

Here, when I debug I see that `self is nil`, and `self.article is also nil`.

And I get this error

> `undefined method phase_id for nil:NilClass.`

How can I get `article object` in `mytest` method?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: basically I am trying to pass error to parent object if validation fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate through the children objects in the parent's validation method and add the errors there instead.

Please see similar question: [Ruby on Rails: how to get error messages from a child resource displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680016/ruby-on-rails-how-to-get-error-messages-from-a-child-resource-displayed)